# PHP while loop. Why does this work?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I'm creating my first php site using tutorial for reference. I can't get my head around why the following works:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row[1]. " ".row[2]."<br/>";
}
```

Specifically, how does the loop increment to the next row?

UPDATE:
Thanks to all who bothered to provide an answer, including those who implored me to RTM. My problem was not understanding how while loops work, rather simply I couldn't see how the loop increments.
THE ANSWER:
From the PHP docs,

mysql_fetch_array: Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row **and moves the internal data pointer ahead**

I see now, all is well.

Comment: Read its documentation.

Comment: BTW PLEASE USE "mysqli_fetch_array" specifically the mysqli.

Comment: Like c, the function mysql_fetch_array grabs a row from a table sequentially, like a placeholder and returns 0 or false when it reaches the end. this value gets assigned to row, but its also read by the if statement

Comment: Please accept the answer you're most satisfied with rather than putting the answer in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite that code to this equivalent:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); // fetch and advance
while ($row !== false) { // compare result against false
  echo $row[1]. " ".row[2]."<br/>";
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); // fetch and advance
}
```

An assignment yields a value which can then be used in a condition, though it's a good practice to put parentheses around the assignment:

```
// fetch and advance, compare fetched result against false
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false) {
  echo $row[1]. " ".row[2]."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: There is an even better practice of not putting an assignment into a condition expression.

Comment: @ragol - I'm asking just for my own knowledge, why it is not a better practice to not put an assignment into the condition clause ? I've seen the pattern in many open source code (particularly in mail() calls). What's wrong with it ?

Comment: @ragol That's not exactly universal and really depends on which code convention you wish to follow.

Comment: Thanks @Jack. Your answer hints at the cause of my confusion. I understand now that the mysql_fetch_array command advances the internal pointer so all is good.

Comment: @AyeshK: It is not *bad* to put assignments into conditional expressions. It's just that code becomes less readable, because it is not obvious at first glance whether it is a typo in a place where a comparison operator is expected or a real assignment. So you should think twice before putting an assignment into conditionals.

Comment: @Jack: True, it's not universal. It's just a hint that you should think before you type, because the readability of code suffers.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array() will take a $result and save into $row in form an array. Using while loop, your program will loop the data in the array from the beginning until the end.

By the way, your codes should be like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['someData1']. " ".row['someData2']."<br/>";
}
```

If you want to iterate through the index, then the code looks like following but it will print the word Array as you will print the result in "that" specific index.

```
$indexCounter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row[$indexCounter]."<br/>";
}
```

Hope this helps! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_fetch_array take the first element of $result then is $result have elements this work... is like take cards from a deck

Answer (score 0):

Take a read though the [**PHP While**](https://www.php.net/while) documentation. It might also be useful to learn what [**mysql_fetch_array()**](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) does and how it works. After you're done reading about that, don't use the `mysql_*` functions again because they're deprecated. Instead, use [`mysqli_*`](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/pdo).